# MooTools Chaining

Tags: javascript, mootools, method-chaining

I don't think a function/method should ever return void—instead, it should return `this`. That's why I was surprised to find out that this doesn't work:

```
$('buttonContainer').getElement('input').set('value', this.get('value') + '  ');
```

What the code is suppose to do is find an `<input>` that is a child of the element with `id` attribute value of `buttonContainer`, and add two space characters to its `value` attribute. The aforeshown code errors though, and I'm forced to write:

```
var input = $('buttonContainer').getElement('input');
input.set('value', input.get('value') + '  ');
```

Doesn't MooTools have a way to chain these two seperate statements into one? Something similar to my first snippet?

Answer (score 3):

MooTools cannot rebind `this` on the fly for every method called. This would be impossible.

You have to understand that every single call to your chain is in the same scope, therefore `this` remains the same. jQuery and every single other framework have the same problem. If you want to do two operations on an element at the same time, you must store the object in a variable and then use that variable to reference the object exactly like you did in your second example:

```
var input = $('buttonContainer').getElement('input');
input.set('value', input.get('value') + '  ');
```

`this` can only change when the scope changes (which in JavaScript is always when you hit a brace `{}` enclosing a function). This is not a limitation of MooTools' chaining. It's the way JavaScript in general works.

Comment: @Andrew, I know what you are trying to say, but in JS you hit braces a lot (`if`, `for`, `while`, `switch`, `try`), and the *only* time it changes scope is when those braces are associated with a function.

Comment: @Doug: Thanks, small oversight on my part, I've edited the answer to correct this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking has nothing to do with chaining. `this` has no context, so your call fails. The solution you are not happy with is the way you will need to write it for other values/attributes, but for a straight forward change like this, write it this way:

```
$('buttonContainer').getElement('input').value += '  ';
```